# FFMPEG- how to set presentation timestamp of a second video while merging a second video side-by-side with a first video

Tags: ffmpeg

I was trying to merge a second video into a first video, side-by-side in a stacked fashion as a self-interest work. The twist is the video is a recording of a video call, where a second user might join at a later stage than the first user. The cumulative recording of the video call must reflect that the second user joins at a later stage than the first user. For this, I am using this code:

```
DIFF=$(($start_ts-$BASEts))
DIFFms=`echo "scale=0;$DIFF/1000" | bc`
DIFFs=`echo "scale=4;$DIFF/1000000" | bc`
ffmpeg -i $a.webm -i b.webm -filter_complex \
    "[0]pad=2*iw:1*ih[l];[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+$DIFFs/TB[1v]; [l][1v]overlay=x=W/2[v]; \
    [1]adelay=$DIFFms|$DIFFms[1a]; \
    [0][1a]amix=inputs=2[a]" \
    -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -vcodec libvpx -cpu-used -5 -deadline realtime finalOutput.webm
```

However, the error being thrown here is:

```
[Parsed_setpts_1 @ 0x55ada9df1dc0] [Eval @ 0x7ffff35acb60] Undefined constant or missing '(' in '/TB'
[Parsed_setpts_1 @ 0x55ada9df1dc0] Error while parsing expression 'PTS-STARTPTS+/TB'
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x55ada9d6c2a0] Error initializing filter 'setpts' with args 'PTS-STARTPTS+/TB'
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument
```

It is unable to read the $DIFFs variable at all, is what I figured. Can anybody help me out here?